# Upload File through FTP in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ftp

I am having a bit of trouble with my software. I am wanting to upload a simple `xml` file to a server through FTP. I am not really sure how to do this in Objective-C. I saw something like this, but it really did not help me upload a file:

```
url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://username:pw@189.92.32.34"];
```

I am more familiar with C#, but how would i go about uploading a file through FTP?

Thanks,

Elite Gamer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

You do the request and set the stream delegate:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://username:pw@189.92.32.34"];
CFReadStreamRef stream = CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url);
stream.delegate= self;
[stream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[stream open];
```

Then you handle it with this method:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode;
```

**PS**: Release the stream with CFRelease() when you don't need it anymore.

**Reference**

CFNetworking framework (look at the CFFTP API): https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Concepts/Concepts.html

Sample: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: How would i do the upload?

Comment: thanks, but could you write some code just to get me started...i just need somewhere to start. Thanks